# How do I match a field of a collection with a field inside array of another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collection in MongoDb and say :

**Collection1**

```
[ {"Name" : "foo1", "Place" : "bar1", "Rank" : 1},
  {"Name" : "foo2", "Place" : "bar2", "Rank" : 2},
  {"Name" : "foo3", "Place" : "bar3", "Rank" : 3} ]
```

**Collection2**

```
[ {"DocNo" : "One",
   "DocArray" : [{"Name" : "ABC", "Number" : 1},
                 {"Name" : "DEF", "Number" : 2},
                 {"Name" : "XYZ", "Number" : 4}]},
  {"DocNo" : "Two",
   "DocArray" : [{"Name" : "JKL", "Number" : 5},
                 {"Name" : "GHI", "Number" : 1},
                 {"Name" : "UVW", "Number" : 3}]}
]
```

I need to write a query in **Collection1** where I have the `DocNO` to get the search from **Collection2** and return only those documents from **Collection1** where `Rank` field matches all the `Number` fields of all elements inside the `DocArray` for that particular document.

In this example if I have `DocNo = "Two"` then the returned array would be something like this :

```
[ {"Name" : "foo1", "Place" : "bar1", "Rank" : 1},
  {"Name" : "foo3", "Place" : "bar3", "Rank" : 3}]
```

I need to do all this in a single mongo query

Comment: Why do you wanted to start on `Collection 1` instead of `Collection 2` if you've a particular `DocNO` that you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement :

> I need to write a query in Collection1

But I would say you need to start this aggregation on `Collection 2` & use `$lookup` stage on `Collection 1`

**Query :**

```
db.Collection2.aggregate([
  { $match: { DocNo: "Two" } }, // Filter for matching doc
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Collection1",
      localField: "DocArray.Number",
      foreignField: "Rank",
      as: "Collection1_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qKnhPUrGBqK)

Comment: Sorry but I need to aggregate it on Collection1 itself. Thanks

Comment: Also is it possible to use `DocArray.Number` as it is an array so I assume it would need some index like `DocArray[1].Number` but I need to filter it for all elements inside DocArray - this question if I were to take your advice and query on Collection2

Comment: @prince47 : If you observe clearly in playground link we're using an array , it can be done !! Is there any reason to start on `Collection 1` I feel it's pointless to start on `Collection 1` if things are being easily done when we start with `Collection 2`

Comment: Yes. There's a specific reason to start with `Collection1` hence my question.

Comment: @prince47 : Are you still looking for this or got an answer ?

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you.